# Sending logstash logs directly to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is it possible to send logstash logs directly to elasticsearch?

For example, can i add something to log4j2 file for solve this?

Or may be exists some plugin for visualizing logstash logs?

Logstash 5.1

Upd: For right understanding i mean the logs that logstash create in time of data processing (his logs), not the logs as data.

Answer (score 2):

After consulting with Elasticsearch guys: there's no pre-built feature in Logstash

Answer (score 0):

Logstash was built to send logs to elasticsearch, so yes, it's quite possible.  See [the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html).

Once the logs are in elasticsearch, the classic was to visualize them is with [kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana), but other products provide overlapping/complementary features.

Comment: Excuse me, may be my question been not clear enough... I know how the Logstash and Kibana working:) I wrote about logs, that Logstash creates in time of data processing.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't clear :)  It's possible to use logstash to send its own logs to elasticsearch (just another file{} input), but I wouldn't recommend it.  If I have space, I setup a single-node cluster to handle the LS/ES logs from the main cluster.

Comment: Yes, it is one of the options:) Anyway the direct send option not exists in logstash (I consults with elasticsearch guys)